# Inbound email service doesn't set plainTextBody on multipart/alternative with text/plain content

Tags: email, apex-email-service

I'm building my first InboundEmail service, and was surprised to find that the automated emails I'm trying to process aren't having their `plainTextBody` attribute set.

The messages have the following Content-Type:

```
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_1461499227631373411110121JavaMailtomcatPRDMYCC2xxxxxxxx_"
```

And contain two sections, a plain text:

```
--_000_1461499227631373411110121JavaMailtomcatPRDMYCC2xxxxxxxx_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And an html:

```
--_000_1461499227631373411110121JavaMailtomcatPRDMYCC2xxxxxxxx_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

In my email service, the `plainTextBody` is `null` and the `htmlBody` is set to the text/html part.

I had assumed that the email service would populate both attributes with the appropriate sections from the email.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or do I need to modify my service to parse the HTML portion of the email instead?

Comment: It is certainly possible -- once, by mistake, I built an SFDC outbound VF email with only HTML body, no text body.  SFDC itself happily sent this email out without text body. -- note: When my email client, 'Zimbra', received the message it displayed a big block: 'No text content' right above the HTML content.

Comment: In this case, the emails appear to contain both a `text/plain` and `text/html` part.  It seems like SFDC isn't populating `plainTextBody` if it's able to populate `htmlBody`.